# Drag Mac OS full screen window out of full screen mode

Tags: macos, display, window, fullscreen, workflow

Trying to get used to using Mac as my main workhorse. One annoying thing is window management and workflow between windows which of its many failings Windows seems to do better at generally moving windows around!

My question is, while a window is in full screen mode, how can I drag it and make it snap out of (without navigating to the green button) full screen mode, like I would in Windows.

I'm looking for tools, software, hacks that would allow me to do this. Having to first press the green button, wait for it to resize then move the window is just too many steps for the simple alternative that a Windows PC has.

Thank you.

Comment: The default key combo to bring a window in full screen mode in macOS and OS X (by the way, which one do you have? OS X is ancient now...) is Command + Control + F. There are third-parties that allow you to resize windows from anything other than the bottom right corner, which is default behavior in macOS (and OS X...). See here (and the links at the bottom of the page) for more details: https://osxdaily.com/2016/12/06/use-window-snapping-mac/

Comment: Thanks for the comment but what I'm trying to do is not add anymore work to the process. I just want to drag the window while its in full screen mode and have the window respond when I do that. What it does now is just ignore the drag, even though if you hover on the window it presents the titlebar with the green button, it ignores any actions on the title bar. So unless you do the keystroke, or press the green button you cant move the window. I'm asking if there is a quicker one step way to drag instantly from Full screen mode, maybe an app?

Comment: There are a few third-parties that pick up where Apple left off in terms of window management, but they're seldom free (https://beebom.com/best-window-manager-apps-mac/). Spectacle IS free, but apparently it comes with a few bugs, as several macOS users here have noticed (and complained about). It's worth a try, but they all work along the same (rigid) lines imposed by Apple and its APIs. Each window in any given application works in its own process in macOS or OS X (Tiger and above), so to prevent buffer overflow attacks and virtual memory management issues, Apple doesn't give much leeway...

Comment: ... This said, some windows can be dragged around but weren't designed to be resized or snapped to corners. Mostly system messaging windows in OS X have fixed size and position, that's set by the system, and can't be easily modified.

Comment: Mosaic seems to be a good app to handle windows, and you just have to avoid full screen mode as its a very sticky window state to get out of. https://www.lightpillar.com/mosaic.html